# Show HTML in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I remember there was a way to show HTML directly in phpMyAdmin. I want to display images in phpMyAdmin by using `<img>` tags. Or, is there another way to display images in phpMyAdmin?

I'm using phpMyAdmin 3.4.5 with MySQL 5.5

Comment: why is this closed as off topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a new row to your database table with PHPMyAdmin, choose VARBINARY as column data type and use the browser transformation feature:

[image]